# R Dplyr Group Subtraction

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data

```
DATA = data.frame(STUDENT=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5),
TIME=c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1),
SCORE=c(6, 9, 9, 5, 5, 5, 8, 9))
```

and try to make this

```
DATA2 = data.frame(STUDENT=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
SCOREDIFFERENCE=c(3, -4, 0, NA, NA))
```

where I take SCORE[TIME==2]-SCORE[TIME==1] for all STUDENT and when there is only one measure then the value SCOREDIFFERENCE is NA

I try this:

`DATA2 = DATA %>% group_by(STUDENT) %>% mutate(SCOREDIFFERENCE = SCORE[TIME==2]-SCORE[TIME==1])` without successes

Answer (score 4):

A solution using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

DATA = data.frame(STUDENT=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5),
TIME=c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1),
SCORE=c(6, 9, 9, 5, 5, 5, 8, 9))

DATA %>% pivot_wider(names_from = TIME, values_from = SCORE) %>% 
  group_by(STUDENT) %>% 
  summarise(SCOREDIFF = `2`-`1`)

# A tibble: 5 × 2
# STUDENT SCOREDIFF
# <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1         3
# 2        -4
# 3         0
# 4        NA
# 5        NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `diff` in `summarise`, with `.by = STUENT`

```
DATA %>%
    summarise(SCOREDIFF = if (n() < 2) NA else diff(SCORE), .by = STUDENT)
```

or as @LMc suggested

```
DATA %>%
    summarise(SCOREDIFF = SCORE[2] - SCORE[1], .by = STUDENT)
```

which gives

```
  STUDENT SCOREDIFF
1       1         3
2       2        -4
3       3         0
4       4        NA
5       5        NA
```

Comment: +1 How about simply `SCORE[2] - SCORE[1]`? If `SCORE[2]` does not exist then it will return `NA` and the result of `NA - SCORE[1]` will be `NA`, which is the expected behavior.

Comment: @LMc aha, that's cool! I will update the answer with yours :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option from base.

```
DATA = data.frame(STUDENT=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5),
                  TIME=c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1),
                  SCORE=c(6, 9, 9, 5, 5, 5, 8, 9))
aggregate(SCORE ~ STUDENT, data= DATA,  FUN = "diff") |> 
     setNames(c("STUDENT", "Diff"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively with `lead`

```r
DATA %>% group_by(STUDENT) %>% mutate(SCOREDIFFERENCE=lead(SCORE)-SCORE) %>% slice_head(n=1)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 4
# Groups:   STUDENT [5]
  STUDENT  TIME SCORE SCOREDIFFERENCE
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
1       1     1     6               3
2       2     1     9              -4
3       3     1     5               0
4       4     2     8              NA
5       5     1     9              NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Robust to the TIME not being in order:

```
DATA %>%
  reframe(score_dif = SCORE[TIME==2] - SCORE[TIME==1], .by = STUDENT)
```